# How do I get every user's id in a server into an array? (Discord.js v12)

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, discord.js

I need help with getting all users id in a server. I already tried all solutions, apparently, it won't work for me.

I already tried this (which is the most relevant to me)

// Get the Guild and store it under the variable "list"
const list = client.guilds.cache.get("335507048017952771");

// Iterate through the collection of GuildMembers from the Guild getting the username property of each member 
list.members.forEach(member => console.log(member.user.username));

Comment: If you tried ***all*** of htem, there's nothing left to suggest.

Comment: provide some source code to get helpful suggestions.

Comment: well I guess the description should be "I need help with getting all users id in a server. I already tried all the solutions that I can find, apparently, it won't work for me."

Answer (score 2):

The members of a guild are stored in a Collection. You can use the [map()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=map) method to create an array including only the IDs.

```
const Guild = client.guilds.cache.get("335507048017952771"); // Getting the guild.
const Members = Guild.members.cache.map(member => member.id); // Getting the members and mapping them by ID.
console.log(Members);
// --> ["1234567890054356", "1323534709650967", "436567540796390"] etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

Using map works fine but keys() is another solution, which returns a map iterator

```
const list = <Guild>.members.cache.keys();
list.forEach(id => console.log(id));
```

If you want to make it into an array just use spread operator

```
const arr = [...list];
```